# How to use an unprepared statement for MSSQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, prepared-statement, sql-injection

How do I use an unprepared statement for MSSQL in PHP?
So far, I am using this code:

```php
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table;
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
```

But the documentation for sqlsrv_query says, that the statement gets prepared:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-query.php

How do I explicitly use unprepared statements or allow SQL injections in prepared statements?

Comment: As far as I can tell the sqlsrv extension always works with prepared statements. I don't see the harm in that, do you? It is a necessary step. For instance, the [PDO exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) also does a: _"prepare and execute"_.

Comment: Yeah, they do, but I do not want to use prepared statements. I want to *allow* sql injections.

Comment: See above. For demonstration purposes.

Comment: Ah, OK, but you can allow injection even with prepared statements.

Comment: Just use a query like `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name='$username'`, or something similar. Where `$username` is a PHP variable coming from the user.

Comment: Good to know, I just edited my question so that it reflects the purpose I want to achieve. Can you tell me how I allow SQL injections in prepared statements?

Comment: Here are a few examples from the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: The SQL statement does not allow injection as far as i can tell. when I insert 1=1 OR incorrectusername as the username, $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) returns false.

Comment: Prepared statements don't magically solve SQL injection, they're just a tool to do so and you aren't forced to use it—it's still possible to pass hard-coded values in your SQL code.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much KIKO, you were right and I just had some quotation mark issue in my statement. Consider making an answer, I'd accept it ;)

Comment: `$sql` can obviously contain whatever you want, although why you would want to do this is beyond me. There is *almost* nothing you can do with injected SQL that cannot be properly parameterized in most DBMSs